# activemq list doesn't list all running brokers

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I wonder if `activemq list` works as expected. I use ActiveMQ 5.10.2. According to the documentation:

| Task Usage | activemq-admin list [options] |
| --- | --- |
| Description | Script to list the names of all running brokers in the specified JMX context. This task requires that JMX is enabled. |
| `activemq-admin list` | Lists the names of all running brokers in the default JMX context. |

Assuming that you have setup two brokers to not use the same `data` directory in order not to start in master-slave mode, and assuming that they both use the default JMX port `1099`:

```
<managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/>
```

then the 2nd broker will fail to start because it won't be able to connect to the already used port `1099`.

If we use the same `data` directory, then the 2nd broker will start as slave, and as a consequence the command `activemq list` will return only one pid, the one of the master broker. Btw, according to the description of the command, it should also return the broker name, which is more useful to use in other admin commands, but it only returns the pid.

So, I really wonder, what does the sentence "Lists the names of all running brokers in the default JMX context." mean, since you can't start more than one broker in the same JMX context. If you start 2 brokers using 2 different JMX ports, then how do you use the command?

```
activemq-admin list –jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://remotehost:1099/jmxrmi    List the names of all running brokers in the specified JMX context.
```

again requires a single JMX URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run multiple ActiveMQ brokers in the same JVM (and JMX context).  This command generally outputs one entry (since most of the time there is one), but also supports the scenario if there are multiple running the JVM.